# VScode unresolved import

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

Im working on a project and want to start using VScode (currently using sublime). The problem is that when i import the folder and open the files, a lot of functions show undefined-variable and undefined-import for the modules.

The file structure is something like this:

```
trunk
|--libs
    |--proj
         |--module1
         |--module2
|--scripts
    |--script.py
```

and in my script.py i have

`from proj import module1`  (here shows the error undefined-import).

`module1.functionA()` (shows undefined-variable)

Already tried to select the interpreter and reload window in vscode but didnt work.
I found that if i use  `from libs.proj import module1` it works ok, but fails when i run the script. 
In sublime, `from proj import module1` works ok.

Also in my launch.json i have

```
  "env": {
    "PYTHONPATH": "~/Desktop/project/trunk/libs/"
  },
```

We dont work with virtual envs. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

So, digging more into google, found an answer to my problem.

Added in `settings.json` the folow lines:

```
"python.autoComplete.extraPaths": [
  "${workspaceRoot}/libs/"   
],
```

So now `from proj import module1` works fine